# Get shape index in powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I hope this is a super simple question but for some reason i cant figure it out.

I need to delete a subset of the selected shapes on a powerpoint slide using VBA. I can do this using:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(_Index_).Delete
```

Where _Index_ is either an array of shape indexes (integers) or shape names (stings).

Since the shape names are not unique (and people i am making this macro for have a nasty habit of having multiple shapes with the same name) i need to rely on the shape index number. My problem is i dont know how to get the index number of a given shape.

I can only see how i get the shape name or shape ID using:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(IdNum).Name
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(IdNum).ID
```

So my question is: How do i get the shape index of selected shapes?

Comment: The id should give the order they were added to the slide.

Comment: Yes but how can i translate an ID into an index? The Index is always numbered 1 to number of shapes on slide while ID can be anything with gaps in between (e.g., it could be that index 1 has ID 5 and index 2 has ID 211). It seems like there should be an easy way to just get the index..

Comment: I don't think a separate list of indices is maintained for the Shapes collection. You could write a loop over the shapes collection to assign names you can use to differentiate.

Comment: " My problem is i dont know how to get the index number of a given shape."  If by "given" you mean selected, then ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)..ZOrderPosition will give you the index.

Comment: Steve Rindsberg this was exactly what i needed! Thanks a lot! Im not exactly sure how this site works in terms of credit for answers but will you leave your comment as an answer so i can mark it as solved? Thanks again.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg now i have run into another problem with the ZOrderPosition. It works exactly as intended when there are no grouped shapes on the page. For some reason a grouped shapes only has 1 index (like they are treated as 1 shape) while the ZOrderPosition will return a number including all shapes within the groups (e.g., if there are 3 shapes on a page, 2 of them are grouped, then the index of the 3rd shape will be 2 but the ZOrderPosition will be 3).
So now im back at: how do i determine the index of a selected shape if there are grouped shapes on the page?

Comment: @Peter Please see my answer below.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg thanks for the additional answer. But just to clarify, I don’t need to find the index of a shape within a group - I need to find the index of a selected shape (which is not grouped) while there are other grouped shapes on the slide. Lets do an example: there are 3 shapes on a slide. Shape 1 and 2 are grouped. The 3rd shape are selected and we need to find the index. Since shape 1 and 2 are grouped they together have index 1 while shape 3 has index 2. The zOrderPosition of shape 3 is however 3, which is not matching the index. So how can I find the index of the selected shape 3?

Comment: @Peter You're making my head hurt!  ;-)  But that's a great observation/great question, one I'd never run into. See the extra code I tacked onto my earlier answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you group a selection of shapes, the group becomes a new shape appended to the end of the previous z-order position. All of the  individual shapes within the group are appended to the z-order after the group shape itself.

I can't find a way of determining which individual item within a group is selected (sub-selected, I guess we should say, since the original parent group remains selected and that's what PPT returns when you query ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).

To identify the currently subselected item within a group, you can use this as a starting point:

```
Sub WorkWithSubSelectedShapes()
' Do stuff with sub-selected shapes within a group
' Courtesy of Andy Pope

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oGSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long

    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    ' Do something with each shape in the group:
    For Each oGSh In oSh.GroupItems
        Debug.Print oGSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Next

    ' Now do something with each SUB-SELECTED
    ' shape within the group
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ChildShapeRange
        For x = 1 To .Count
            Debug.Print .Item(x).Name
            Debug.Print .Item(x).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Here's some code that may help generally in processing shapes/groups. It takes account of the fact that there might be groups within groups (within groups (within groups)) ...

```
Sub ProcessShapes()

    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        If oSh.Type = msoGroup Then
            Debug.Print "GROUP" & vbTab & oSh.Name & vbTab & oSh.ZOrderPosition

            Call DealWithGroup(oSh)
        Else
            Debug.Print oSh.Name & vbTab & oSh.ZOrderPosition
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub DealWithGroup(oSh As Shape)
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To oSh.GroupItems.Count
        If oSh.GroupItems(x).Type = msoGroup Then
            Call DealWithGroup(oSh.GroupItems(x))
        Else
            Debug.Print "GROUP ITEM" & vbTab & oSh.GroupItems(x).Name & vbTab & oSh.GroupItems(x).ZOrderPosition
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And to answer Peter's further (excellent) question, this should work:

```
Sub TestIndexOf()
    MsgBox IndexOf(ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1))
End Sub

Function IndexOf(oSh As Shape) As Long

    Dim x As Long

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes
        For x = 1 To .Count
            If .Item(x).Name = oSh.Name Then
                ' Found it, report it
                IndexOf = x
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg I had hoped for a more clean way (e.g., like ZOrderPosition without having to loop through shapes) but i guess this gets the job done. One small edit i would make is to change it to compare .ID instead of .Name since (as far as i understand) the ID is unique while the Name is not. Then it will also work if multiple shapes on the slide has the same name.

Comment: @Peter Good point. While names are theoretically unique, PowerPoint has a habit of sometimes creating multiple same-named shape, which can cause all sorts of odd problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try the few lines of code and yow will get names of all the shapes in immediate window (Cttl+G to view Immediate window)

```
Dim shp As Shape, I As Integer
For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
I = I + 1
Debug.Print "Index=" & I & " Name= " & shp.Name & " ID= " & shp.Id & " Type= " & shp.Type
Next
```