# VBA to rename all PowerPoint shape groups to text box content

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a slide deck with 1700+ slides. Each slide has two images on it. Each image also has a text box underneath it with a unique identifier. Each image is grouped with the text box. The group names are not unique.

So on all slides, I have in the selection pane:

---

Group 8
Rectangle 7
Picture 7

Group 4
Rectangle 3
Picture 2

---

The rectangle shape is the text box containing the UID. The photo's alt text also includes the UID.

What I need to do is programmatically rename "Group 8" and "Group 4" with the content of the text boxes (i.e., my UID). Can this be accomplished fairly easily via VBA? Renaming each group name in the selection pane will be a nightmare.

Any thoughts on feasibility here would be appreciated, or perhaps there's some VBA I can tweak to accomplish this.

I've tried manually renaming in the selection pane, but that's not feasible.

Comment: Try and have a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74339634/18247317) I received for a very similar request.

Answer (score 1):

Provide code will update groups' name with the text on rectangle shape.

Please updated the code as needed if you are using TextBox (Insert >> TextBox).

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| msoAutoShap | 1 | AutoShape |
| msoTextBox | 17 | Text Box |

Please refers to Microsoft document.

[MsoShapeType enumeration (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Sub UpdateGroupNames()
    Dim objPresentation As Object
    Dim objSlide As Object
    Dim objShape As Object
    Dim oShpInGrp As Object
    Set objPresentation = ActivePresentation
    For Each objSlide In objPresentation.Slides
        For Each objShape In objSlide.Shapes
'            Debug.Print objShape.Type
            If objShape.Type = 6 Then 'group shape
                For Each oShpInGrp In objShape.GroupItems
                    If oShpInGrp.Type = 1 Then ' Rectangle (AutoShape)
                        objShape.Name = oShpInGrp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next oShpInGrp
            End If
        Next objShape
    Next objSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: This should work nicely. One comment:  Set objShape = objShape isn't necessary.